# How to make secondary Y-Axis dependent on primary Y-Axis in a line chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I'm pretty new to c# and really need to get this done. I know how to add secondary y axis to a line chart , but it's a little different here in my problem. . I have a chart which already has one x and one y axis . the x axis represents `DateTime` and the y axis is some integer values related to the `DateTime`. The data source is a data set filled with a reader from SQL. I need to add a second y axis to the chart which shows how many data points there are in the series related to each value of first y axis. The language is C#. 
Here are the code and the result image:

```
chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
chart1.Controls.Clear();
chart1.Series[0] = new Series();
chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
chart1.DataSource = table;
chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = table.Columns["ltime"].ColumnName; 
chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = table.Columns["ttkh"].ColumnName; 
chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 30;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;     
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;     
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.MinorTickMark.Enabled = true; 
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Maximum = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum;     

int sMax=(int)chart1.Series[0].Points.Select(x=>x.YValues[0]).Max<double();
double[] sums = new double[sMax + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < chart1.Series[0].Points.Count; i++)  
{
    int val = (int)chart1.Series[0].Points[i].YValues[0];    
    sums[val] += 1;                           
}
for (int i = 0; i < sums.Length; i++)
{
    CustomLabel cl = new CustomLabel();
    cl.Text = sums[i].ToString("###0");
    cl.FromPosition = i - 0.5;
    cl.ToPosition = i + 0.5;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.CustomLabels.Add(cl);
}
chart1.DataBind();
```

[It shows customLabled with no values!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dimGo.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) SO page about how to extend your question about a problem caused by your code. Currently your question doesn't show any particular effort showing your research.

Comment: Create an extra `Series`, populate it with the information you want to see and associate it with the secondary Y-Axis.

Comment: Tag your question properly: `WinForms` ? `WPF` ? `ASP.NET` ?

Comment: @jstreet, It's a winForm

Comment: Ok, i added the tag for you. You can always select **edit** and add proper tags yourself next time.

Answer (score 1):

It took my a while to understand what you want but I think this could be it:

[image]

Not very hard to do, if you know about `CustomLabels`.

- You calculate the sums
- You synch the two y-axes to the same scale
- you place custom labels with the sums at the right spots

Here is a function to add the secondary `Y-Axis` and `CustomLabels` for each value of your data showing the count for that value.

Of course this can only work with **distinct** values. My code assumes `integer` values but I guess you could adapt it to `decimals` as well.. Note that it will not work well with `floats` or `doubles`! You would have to expand the summing code to set up something like a `Dictionary<float, int>` instead of the simple `array`..

```
void addSumSeries(Chart chart, Series s)
{
    ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];       // short name

    CA.AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;      // turn on secondary y-axis
    CA.AxisY2.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;       // no grid lines
    CA.AxisY2.MinorTickMark.Enabled = true;    // show tick marks
    CA.AxisY2.Maximum = CA.AxisY.Maximum;      // synch display scale

    // find the maximum value; we'll show all values from 0 to sMax
    int sMax = (int) s.Points.Select(x => x.YValues[0]).Max<double>();  
    double[] sums = new double[sMax + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Points.Count; i++ )      // loop over data
    {
        int val = (int) s.Points[i].YValues[0];    // get value
        sums[val] += 1;                            // count values
    }

    // now create custom labels: each shows the count..
    // ..and is placed in the middle between the last and the next value
    for (int i = 0; i < sums.Length; i++)
    {
        CustomLabel cl = new CustomLabel();
        cl.Text = sums[i].ToString("###0"); // to get that right you'd need special spaces
        cl.FromPosition = i - 0.5;
        cl.ToPosition = i + 0.5;
        CA.AxisY2.CustomLabels.Add(cl);
    }
}
```

And here is how I set up my test data:

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.ChartAreas.Clear();
    chart1.Series.Clear();
    ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas.Add("CA");
    Series S1 = chart1.Series.Add("S1");
    S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;

    DateTime now = DateTime.Now.Date;
    CA.AxisX.Minimum = now.AddHours(-12).ToOADate();
    CA.AxisY.Maximum = 16;
    // create a few test data with values 1-15
    // every couple of days
    Random R = new Random(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
    {
        DateTime dt = now.AddDays(R.Next(4)+i);
        S1.Points.AddXY(dt, R.Next(16) );
    }

    // call the function that adds the counting axis:
    addSumSeries(chart1, S1);
}
```

Note that this calculation needs to be done after you have added (or changed) the data points!

Of course it will work as well with line charts, but, at least for my data, this looks cooler..

**Update**:

For a data bound chart the`Points` are empty. So instead we must calculate the sums from the datasource.

Here are some lines to do just that; they make use of a `DataTable dt`:

```
// convert to a list of rows:
List<DataRow> query = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();

int sMax = (int)query.Select(x => (int)(x[1])).Max<int>();  // find the maximum value

double[] sums = new double[sMax + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < query.Count(); i++)      // loop over data
    {
        int val = (int)(query[i]["ttkh"]);    // get value
        sums[val] += 1;                       // count values
}
```

Looking at the image I should warn you, that the way the sums are calculated they may result in up to 500 distinct values, each with a CustomLabel! If that's too much you would have to think of a variation; maybe you can create groups on value ranges of 10 or so..

Here is an example:

Using a variable `int groupSize = 10`  or whatever works for you you can change the summing code to:

```
 sums[val / groupSize] += 1;
```

and the positioning and labelling of the custom labels to:

```
cl.Text = sums[i].ToString(groupSize * i + " - " +  (groupSize * (i +1) - 1) +  ":  ###0");
cl.FromPosition = i * groupSize - 0.5;
cl.ToPosition = i * groupSize + 0.5;
```

[image]

For unbound charts you could add a `ToolTip` to each `DataPoint` the show the `Y-Value` and the corresponding count; this doesn't seemt to be possible for data bound charts however, which only support `ToolTips` at the `Series` level. These are restricted to using [a few keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd456687%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and can't be set on a per point basis.

Comment: what you have depicted above is exactly what I want to achieve. Just give me some time to apply it to my code and see what happens. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Sure, take your time and if you have questions please ask.

Comment: It just shows customLabled with no values. I edited my question to upload my own code along with yours docked in. You can also find the result image in the link below the code. Thanks.

Comment: In your updated answer I see that your Chart is data bound. Such details are important! I have updated the answer with a few lines that adapts the code to calculate not from the Points but from the DataTable..

Comment: Thank you so much for the comprehensive explanations. I'll apply the lates changes you have pointed out above and let you iff it works. Guess you're right about the messy look og customLables. I wanted to try and see the output but I had searched also (as a back up plan) to find a way to use tooltip. I guess it's more reasonable. Will study the tooltip thing through the net. You said it's not possible for a data bound chart. Can the chart type be changed then. Try to find it out. If got stuck again will ask for more help.